# What does "on the go" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Only 12% of campaigns run for less than a week. That allows plenty of time for **on-the-go** learning to emerge. Letting learning from the previous mailing to inform the next one turns a series of messages into a managed conversation over time.

What does "on the go" mean here?

Comment: Hi user123. We encourage people to do a bit of research before posting questions here. That means things like checking a dictionary first. If you have already checked a dictionary and you still don't understand, please clarify what you found from the dictionary and **why** the sentence is still unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "on-the-go learning" is similar to "on-the-job learning" in the context of the OP's quoted sentence. You learn something while you are doing the job or while you are on your way to some place.

I found another example of the term.

**Parents – Ideas for On-the-Go Learning**

Teachable moments are everywhere! You can often help your child sharpen important skills by integrating lessons with everyday activities. Walk down the sidewalk, peek into kitchen cupboards or see highway signs with fresh eyes. Check back often for new ideas.

```
Math/Numbers/Patterns
Letters/Words/Language
Science & Hands-on Experimentation
Imagination/Focus/Critical Thinking
Recipes for Fun & Learning
```

Comment: thanks. what dose last part mean "Letting learning from the previous mailing to inform the next one turns a series of messages into a managed conversation over time."

Comment: Letting learning from the previous mailing to inform the next one [the subject] turns [the verb] a series of messages [the object] into a managed conversation over time [the prepositional phrase]. I am not sure how to explain this except to analyze the sentence structure.